# Panel Event Study

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I want to perform a panel data event study using quarterly data. I have collected time series data on stock prices for approx. 1000 firms from 29 different industries over a 365 day period. My goal is to test for abnormal returns in stock markets as a result of war. However, the methodology seems mixed on the best way to approach this.

My plan was to use an event study method to look at the impact of war on all firms in the dataset, then performing a cross sectional regression to look at the impact per industry.

Is a standard event study approach as described in MacKinlay (1997) sufficient for this purpose?
Here's the link to the paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2729691?seq=1
Some literature just use WRDS's event study tool to perform the analysis.

But I have also come across literature that argues for panel event study methodology where the regression looks as follows:
[image]

If the last method is indeed the most appropriate, can anyone suggest a paper/video using this methodology?

I have tried to look for posts with similar questions but have not found any specific to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Data like this has been extensively analyzed without a *standard model* emerging from the literature. The econometric bible is Wooldridge's *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*. https://ipcig.org/evaluation/apoio/Wooldridge%20-%20Cross-section%20and%20Panel%20Data.pdf But Pesaran's voluminous *Time Series and Panel Data Econometrics* is much more applied. https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/time-series-and-panel-data-econometrics-9780198759980?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: Welcome. Can you provide a link to this paper?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yes of course. Here is the link to the paper mentioned: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2729691?seq=1